# rewrite_rules problem

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, loop, scheduled-posts

I am using scheduled posts as a event program, by making a loop pick up future posts.

Every now and again, the production site starts to show 404's for the single event pages, and to fix it I have to copy the contents of the `rewrite_rule` option from my local database, to production.

Does anyone know what is going wrong, and if I can prevent it?

---

**Edit**

It's worth noting that it was *only* the future events that get the `404`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to flush your rewrite rules. There is a [**flush_rewrite_rules()**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) function, although the codex isn't terribly useful with how it is used.

Comment: I switched to default permalink rules, which removed the `rewrite_rules` option. Does flushing the rewrite rules go beyond this?

Comment: @MildFuzz I'm not 100% sure to be honest

Comment: the codex doesn't even seem to know. It's a mystery!!

Comment: @Mildfuzz so it would seem. I would experiment with it, but currently don't have a Wordpress installation to work from.